# Пример бота discord на python

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Сделайте пожалуйста готовый код бота в discord на python который будет при команде /random присылать рандомное число от 1 до 600
Это для того чтобы я понимал как оно работает

Comment: "Готовый код" на данном сайте это оффтопик

Comment: Понятно. Вопрос удалить или может мне напишут?

Comment: @andreymal, а по-моему нормальный вопрос. Хотя проще было бы на ютьюбе найти.

Comment: На ютубе только старые видео и я предпологаю что библиотека уже 5 тыщ раз обновилась и толку от ютуба ноль

Comment: @Qwertiy нет, вопрос слишком общий

Comment: @andreymal в каком смысле слишком общий?

Comment: @Денис в таком, что он содержит как минимум две не связанные друг с другом подзадачи: получение команды из discord и генерация случайного числа

Comment: Но кто-то же это сделал правда я ещё не проверял @andreymal

Comment: @Денис ну вот выяснилось, что этот «кто-то» — это нейронная сеть, которая написала код с ошибками ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: И всё-таки, пример минимального бота, очевидно, есть в [официальной документации discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html), и с intents там тоже всё в порядке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример кода на Python для создания Discord-бота, который при получении команды "/random" будет отправлять случайное число от 1 до 600 в текстовый канал:

```
import discord
import random

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('/random'):
        await message.channel.send(random.randint(1, 600))

client.run('YOUR_DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN')
```

Обратите внимание, что вам нужно будет заменить "YOUR_DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN" на токен вашего Discord-бота. Если вы еще не создали свой Discord-бот и получили токен, можете сделать это на странице https://discord.com/developers/applications/.

Comment: А может возникнуть ошибка с intents?

Comment: А могу ли я дальше в функции on_message писать например elif?

Comment: @Денис elif - это уже к синтаксису языка относится, пишите в IDE, если не будет светится красным, то можете (: Касательно intents, если вы получаете ID клиента и прочее, то ошибки не будет.

Comment: @Денис если у вас возникают вопросы подобного уровня, то вам стоит сперва изучить основы python, прежде чем приступать к написанию ботов

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\###\Desktop\dsbot\bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    client = discord.Client()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents' 
все равно ошибка

Comment: @Денис `intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)` - сперва пройдите базовый курс по Python, постарайтесь вывести те же рандомные числа в консоль.

Comment: Это уже слишком базовый import random print(random.randint(1,600))

Comment: Ответ получен с помощью ChatGPT? Мне такой-же выдал ответ ))

Comment: @СергейШ я не знаю этих ваших "чатов ГПТ" или как вы их называете. Любые совпадения являются совпадениями :)